# New Year challenge

Tags: arithmetic

if i did one push up on Jan 1st 2014 and I did two push ups the next day Jan 2 2014 than 3 times on Jan 3rd 2014 what would I be at by the end of the year? How many pushups would I have done throughout the whole year?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number

Comment: 66,795. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: @Devon, 3 times of first day or 3 times of second day?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where do you have difficulties? What you are trying to evaluate is $1+2+3+...+365$. Have you ever seen this sum?

Answer (score 8):

Ask your twin brother to do 365 pushups on Jan 1st, 364 pushups on Jan 2nd, ..., 2 pushups on Dec 3oth, and 1 pushup on Dec 31st.

1. How many pushups do you and your twin brother do in total each day?
2. How many pushups do you and your twin brother do in total in the whole year?
3. How many pushups does each of you do in the whole year?

Comment: +1. I find this to be a very intuitive and pedagogic approach!

Answer (score 1):

Go by Arithmetic Series formula.

Sum of first n terms of an A.P. is
     Sn = (n/2)[2a +(n -1)d]

1+2+3+...+365 = (365/2)*(2*1+(365-1)*1) = 66795

Answer (score 0):

You do $1$ push-up on the first day, $2$ on the second, and generally $n$ push-ups on day $d_n$. So, on the day $d_{365}$, you will do 365 push-ups.

The total number of push-ups is $T=1+2+3+...+365$

Note, you can also write this as $T=365+364+363+...+1$.

Add these two, thus getting:$2T=366+366+...365\text{ times}$

So, ${T}={{366×365}\over{2}}={66795}$